# Brake cable end anchor, which metal?

Tags: brakes, cable

Does anyone know from which material these brake cable end caps (anchors) are made out? Is it lead, some galvanized metal or something else?

[image: Afbeeldingsresultaat voor brake cable end cap stack]

[image: cantilevr brake pad]

Answer (score 3):

It's definitely not lead. Manufacturers have worked out that selling products with lumps of toxic heavy metal attached is not a good idea anymore.

Probably a zinc alloy that can be easily cast onto the end of the steel wire.

Comment: Regardless of toxicity, lead would be much, much too soft.

Comment: @DavidRicherby lead-tin alloy might be hard enough

Comment: It won't be lead at all, else you'd see "known to cause cancer in the state of california" written on packaging.